# PHPExcell выдает ошибку из-за версии файла

Tags: php

Использую библиотеку PHPExcell, выдает ошибку

```
Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 82
```

Код:

```
<?php
require_once ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
$xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("Прайс.xlsx");
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
var_dump($sheet);
?>
```

Comment: похоже на ошибку парсинга файла, файл содержит корректные данные, формат?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка выдавалась из-за кириллицы в названии.